# Benefits of Repository Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, repository

Folks,

I'm pondering about how I can convince my boss the benefits of repository pattern; especially after coming across the following issue.

Here's a method in the Icecream repository

```
public IEnumerable<Icecream> FindWhere(Func<Icecream, bool> predicate)
        {
            return (from item in nhibernateSession.Linq<Icecream>() select item).AsQueryable<Icecream>()               
                .Where(predicate)                                
                .OrderByDescending(c => c.Id).ToList();
        }
```

Here's a call to the above repository function

```
 Icecream ce = qRepository.FindWhere(
                    (q) =>
                    {
                        return q.Id == 10;
                    }
                ).FirstOrDefault<Icecream>();
```

The dilemma is that all Icecream(s) from the database is loaded into memory before the 'predicate' is applied. At least that's what I inferred from the generated SQL. And that's a big 'NO, NO'.

So, how can I convince someone that a repository pattern, which exhibits the above nature, is worth pursuing. Is there a workaround to avoid the above issue?

thanks
dorman

Answer (score 0):

The repository pattern doesn't assume any type of IOC container.  You can achieve the pattern with any persistence mechanism from flat files to in memory lists to stored procs.  Your issue is with your IOC container or LINQ.